# Access Metadata in portal for Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-10.3, geoportal, arcgis-portal

I'm trying to retrieve the metadata of an items on my portal.

I've been trying that : /sharing/content/items//info/metadata/metadata.xml but it's not working.

I have Portal for Arcgis 10.3 and I've installed geoportal server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is now close :
https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/issues/162.
Il's fully tested with 10.3.1